# Vertically aligning text along the same line across different containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have a container with two other pieces of text inside it - a title and a description, for example:

```css
.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.item-title {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.item-description {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-title">Title</div>
  <div class="item-description">Some descriptive text</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-title">A Much Longer Title</div>
  <div class="item-description">Some other descriptive text</div>
</div>
```

Here's a diagram of the desired effect:

[image: diagram of desired effect]

What I'd like is for the title to be vertically-centred at the same point (blue line), no matter how many lines it wraps over. The description should always stay underneath, the same distance away from the title, top-aligned (red line). So the blue line doesn't move but the red line can.

What I've tried so far:

- Applying a negative Y transform to the title. This worked in that it moved the title up, but the description text did not follow it.
- Margins: tried setting a percentage vertical margin but of course this is relative to the parent's width rather than the height of the element, it didn't have the desired effect.
- Flexbox: same sort of result as margins.
- position: absolute on the title. Works to vertically align the title but then makes it very difficult to align the description.

After experimenting for a while and a lot of reading up, it seems like it might not be possible, but if anyone's managed to solve this I'd be very interested to know how.

Comment: If you make title `flex: 1` you can get this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2083/

Comment: @NenadVracar That gets the top part aligned correctly but seems to take up all the space in the container that isn't taken by the description, which gets pushed to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you. I don't think this is possible with CSS alone.

*Your requirements:*

> What I'd like is for the title to be vertically-centred at the same point (blue line), no matter how many lines it wraps over. The description should always stay underneath, the same distance away from the title, top-aligned (red line). So the blue line doesn't move but the red line can.

The following solution satisfies requirement #1 (blue line). The titles are centered along the same horizontal line.

- Make the top-level parent (`.item`) a flex container.
- Give the first child (`.item-title`) a set proportion of the container space. In my example below, I used `flex-grow: 3`.
- Also give the second child (`.item-description`) a set proportion of the container space. I used `flex-grow: 1`.
- Now vertical centering can be uniform across both containers because they are occupying the same proportions of free space.
- However, the descriptions will also be a proportional distance away from the title element, and cannot remain anchored to the same horizontal axis (red line).

```css
.item {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item-title {
  flex: 3;
  font-size: 28px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.item-description {
  flex: 1;           /* also try flex: 2 for a narrower gap between items */
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  background: blue;
  width: 95vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-title">Title</div>
  <div class="item-description">Some descriptive text</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-title">A Much Longer Title</div>
  <div class="item-description">Some other descriptive text</div>
</div>
<hr>
```

[**jsFiddle demo 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/wxwgkq6e/)

---

The following solution satisfies requirement #2 (red line). The descriptions are always the same distance away from the title. However, the titles are no longer anchored to the same horizontal axis.

- Put both the title and description in a single flex container.
- Use a top margin to set a fixed distance for the description from the title.
- *NOTE: The height of the description and vertical margins will determine how far off the line the title is. In other words, the smaller the description and top margin, the closer the titles get to the blue line goal.*

```css
.item-title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 28px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.item-description {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 95vw;
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
.item {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-title">Title<span class="item-description">Some descriptive text</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-title">A Much Longer Title<span class="item-description">Some other descriptive text</span>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
```

[**jsFiddle demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/wxwgkq6e/1/)

Comment: It's still not entirely there - here the length of the description seems to have an effect on how much space there is between the title and the description, however that gap should always be the same. With this code a long title and short description and a short title and short description have different amounts of space between them.